# I want to make an item on a Windows 7 Jump List run as administrator

Tags: windows-7, uac, jumplist, elevation

Only occasionally I have to open a Visual Studio project with a VS instance running under admin. This is a little inconvenient because I can't use the short-cut for that project in the VS Jump List. How can I modify the Jump List entry to force VS to open that project running as admin? Please note that I'm not trying to avoid providing admin auth to do this. I'm just trying to avoid having to run VS as admin, and then having to open the project from within VS once it opens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem, but your solution doesn't seem to work. When I press Ctrl+Shift+Click, the just list closes and nothing else happens (VS isn't launched)

I found a different solution though it's not exactly what I would hope for: You can set VS to *always* launch as administrator, which also works when you invoke it from the jump list. To do so:

1. Right click on the VS shortcut->Properties->Open File Location
2. Right click on devenv.exe->Properties. In the "Compatability" tab mark the checkbox "Run this program as administrator"

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to modify the Jump List entry.
Just hold down Ctrl + Shift keys while clicking on the short-cut, it will be opened with admin privilege

Comment: This does not work =[